# How to retrieve conversation entries older than 90 days in Messages.app?

Tags: messages, messages-in-icloud

In the preferences for `Messages.app` I have set `Keep Messages` to *Forever* :

[image]

But when scrolling back in a long-lived conversation it is hanging at 90 days:

[image]

I am assuming that were not a coincidence .. So is there some undocumented hard-limit that is coming into play here?  Is there any way to access those older threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have always had 'Keep Messages' set to 'Forever', and I can see even 2-3 years old messages. This iPhone is less than a year old, so obviously the older messages in the conversation have been inherited from my older devices.

Is this happening in one or a few conversations or in all? Did you *ever* have this preference set to anything shorter than 'Forever'?

Comment: I do not recall when/if I had [re-]set the preferences to something besides `Forever` so in any case it is [well] longer than 90 days ago